# Fastify giving a react prop to a render with next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fastify

I am using Next.js's example server with Fastify and experimenting with it and am wondering if there is a way to pass let's say a JSON object as a prop into a render? I've tried to find anything in the documentation and can't find anything for doing this.

The server code I'm using is this,

```
const fastify = require('fastify')();
const Next = require('next');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

fastify.register((fastify, opts, next) => {
    const app = Next({ dev })
    app.prepare().then(() => {

        fastify.get('/', (req, res) => {
            let object = {"hello": "world"}; // object I want to pass as a prop
            return app.render(req.req, res.res, '/index', req.query).then(() => {
                res.sent = true
            })
        })

        next()
    }).catch(err => next(err))
})

fastify.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not specific to `Fastify`, but relevant for all server frameworks.

The basic idea is that `req` & `res` object are passed to Next's `getInitialProps`.

So you can put your data on them.

For example, express's Response object has `locals` attribute that is specific to this job.

So, in order to pass data attach it to req / res.

```js
fastify.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const object = { hello: 'world' }; // object I want to pass as a prop
  res.res.myDataFromController = object;
  return app.render(req.req, res.res, '/index', req.query).then(() => {
    res.sent = true;
  });
});
```

```js
// some next page.jsx

const IndexPage = ({ dataFromGetInitilProps }) => (
  <div> {JSON.stringify(dataFromGetInitilProps, null, 2)} </div>
);

IndexPage.getInitilProps = ctx => {
  const { res } = ctx;

  // res will be on the context only in server-side
  const dataFromGetInitilProps = res ? res.myDataFromController: null; 

  return {
    dataFromGetInitilProps: res.myDataFromController,
  };
};

export default IndexPage;
```